# ArcMap - ArcObjects IGeoFeatureLayer Renderer is giving a NullReferenceException

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net

Refactoring a VBA add-in into VB.NET add-in.

I'm getting:

> An unhandled exception of type ' System.NullReferenceException' occured in MyAddin.dll
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have a class that is calling three methods and it's failing on the first method because of the error I'm facing.

```
        If TypeOf pGFLayer.Renderer Is IUniqueValueRenderer Then
           Call LoadDefaultLegend(pMxDoc, pGFLayer, strSelectedLayer)

           Call RemoveJoin(pMxDoc.FocusMap, pLayer)
           pFLayer.DisplayField = "ACAD_layer"

           Call SelectLayerByName(strSelectedLayer, pMxDoc)
           Exit Sub
        End If
```

Then in the method it's trying to pass a parameter, but that parameter is giving me the unhandlded exception error (pRend = pGeoLayer.Renderer). The location of the .lyr file is fine.

Any ideas?

```
Sub LoadDefaultLegend(ByRef pMxDoc As IMxDocument, ByRef pGFLayer As IGeoFeatureLayer, strSelectedLayer As String)
    gstrHomeDir = "C:\MyApps\TestPlugin\MyPlugin\"

    Dim pGxLayer As IGxLayer
    Dim pGxFile As IGxFile

    pGxLayer = New GxLayer
    pGxFile = pGxLayer

    Dim strMxdPath As String
    Dim strLegendPath As String

    strLegendPath = gstrHomeDir & "\Legends\"
    ' Add correct lyr-file (01, 02, 03, ...)
    strLegendPath = strLegendPath & Right(strSelectedLayer, 2) & ".lyr"

    pGxFile.Path = strLegendPath
    Dim pGeoLayer As IGeoFeatureLayer
    pGeoLayer = pGxLayer.Layer

    'Get the Symbology from the layer
    Dim pRend As IFeatureRenderer
    pRend = pGeoLayer.Renderer

    pGFLayer.Renderer = pRend

    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()
    pMxDoc.UpdateContents()
End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess you would need to open the IGxFile after setting the path. I think you want the IGxFile.Open method, but I'm not 100% sure. I doubt simply setting the path to the layer file is sufficient to open it. Alternatively you could use the ILayerFile open the your layer file: https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000074p000000

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @danielm `ILayerFile` is a more appropriate interface for interacting with a Layer File. Below is a code snippet to get you going:

```vb
Dim sPath As String
sPath = "C:\scratch\test.lyr"
Dim pLayerFile As ILayerFile
pLayerFile = New LayerFile
pLayerFile.Open(sPath)
Dim pGFL As IGeoFeatureLayer
pGFL = pLayerFile.Layer
Dim pURend As IUniqueValueRenderer
pURend = pGFL.Renderer
Console.WriteLine(pURend.ValueCount)
```